# Why do IFR reporting points have odd names?

Tags: faa-regulations, navigation, ifr-navigation

I was checking out some flights on FlightAware and went onto the "Route" page for a flight and I saw these [IFR Reporting Points](http://www.cfinotebook.net/notebook/aircraft-operations/enroute/reporting) with really odd names. Is there a regulatory reason why they have such names?

[image]

[Page I snipped image from](https://flightaware.com/live/flight/UAL779/history/20160527/2035Z/KSFO/KEWR/route)

Comment: I think answers here will be quite opinion-based.  All I know is that the names need to be pronounceable by humans for communication over radio, and there appears to be a 5 letter limit, which is why you get strange combos trying to make a pronounceable name out of 5 letters who knows how many unique times.

Comment: @RyanMortensen There will have to be at least a regulation for that though.

Comment: It's still not clear what's "odd" about these names. Although I have long wondered how it is decided when you can give a "cute" name to a waypoint.

Comment: Names are chosen for their mnemonic value and often relate to local landmarks and attractions. For example there is a reporting point near Green Bay Wisconsin called LMMBO for Lambeau Field where the Packers play.

Comment: Check out the FRDMM 3 and TRUPS 3 arrivals to [KDCA](http://www.google.com/url?q=https://flightaware.com/resources/airport/KDCA/procedures&sa=U&ved=0ahUKEwiFmLO01_vMAhUs74MKHcTIAUkQFggPMAE&sig2=4fXUak1UBfTum8qk7yKnvA&usg=AFQjCNGtpmc8O5elH2YEsYD0-qbT3U_NlQ). They spell out sentences

Comment: [ITAWT-ITAWA-PUDYE-TATT ... IDEED](http://i.stack.imgur.com/FmvfM.png)

Comment: It seems to be about [9,000 5-letter words](http://www.poslarchive.com/math/scrabble/lists/common-5.html) in English (anything else will seems odd to an English person). If ICAO removes entries that are confusing (e.g. THREE, LEVEL or SPEED) or inappropriate in any language (MORON, ITLER, BURNE), the list will be quickly reduced. So it's not surprising to see COSMC, ZORBO, or even MEGSS. Also not all fixes are to be used on ATC communication, some are for procedure design only.